# Load textfiles to android app - Out of memory despite not heavy files

Tags: android, out-of-memory

I cannot, by now, understand why I got an out-of-memory exception when I load 9 different textfiles into my android app. The total size of the textfiles is about 10 MB. And I hade to change to large-heapsize in the manifest file to be able to load these files. Its not a good solution, so I wonder if someone could help me to understand what causes the heapsize to rize over 100 MB.

Another thing, could be a clue of something??, is that when heapsize has climed a bit over 100 MB and allocated memory is sligtly below - all loading is done, something happends:

The garbagecollector makes something immediately when loading is finished - the allocated space falls dramatically from 100 MB to 35 MB.

SO I wonder - what is happening? Why is the loading so memory consuming?

I can say that I have a class called FileManager where all loading taking place.

And because FileManager do not extend Activity, I have to pass a context to this class.
Could it be the context that is memory consuming? I think It may be and I have to move the loading when the app starts app at first.

Here is the FileManager-class

```
 public class FileManager {

private String[][] solarObj,, celestObj, stars, sun, moon, venus, march, jupiter, saturn;
private ArrayList <String[][]> stringObjects = new ArrayList <String[][]> () ; 
private String[] textFile; 
private Context context;
private AssetManager assetManager;

public FileManager(Context context) {

    this.context = context;
    assetManager = context.getResources().getAssets();
    instanciateStrings();

    putStringsToList();

    initializeTextFile();

    for (int array_index = 0; array_index < 9; array_index++) {

        read(this.textFile[array_index], this.stringObjects.get(array_index).length, array_index);
        //printString(array_index);
    }
}


    private void instanciateStrings() {

    this.solarObj = new String[98][4];
    this.celestObj = new String[7][3];
    this.stars = new String[92][7];
    this.sun = new String[14246][15];
    this.moon = new String[14246][15];
    this.venus = new String[14246][15];
    this.march = new String[14246][15];
    this.jupiter = new String[14246][15];
    this.saturn = new String[14246][15];
}


/**
 * Lägger in de tvådimensionella strängvektorerna i en arraylist.
 */
private void putStringsToList() {

    this.stringObjects.add(this.celestObj);
    this.stringObjects.add(this.solarObj);
    this.stringObjects.add(this.stars);
    this.stringObjects.add(this.sun);
    this.stringObjects.add(this.moon);
    this.stringObjects.add(this.venus);
    this.stringObjects.add(this.march);
    this.stringObjects.add(this.jupiter);
    this.stringObjects.add(this.saturn);
}


/**
 * Filnamnen läses in i en strängvektor
 */
private void initializeTextFile() {

    this.textFile = new String[9];

    this.textFile[0] = "celestobj_txt.txt";
    this.textFile[1] = "solarObj_txt.txt";
    this.textFile[2] = "stars_txt.txt";
    this.textFile[3] = "sun_txt.txt";
    this.textFile[4] = "moon_txt.txt";
    this.textFile[5] = "venus_txt.txt";
    this.textFile[6] = "march_txt.txt";
    this.textFile[7] = "jupiter_txt.txt";
    this.textFile[8] = "saturn_txt.txt";
}




    private void read(String text_file, int len, int index) {

    String[] stringBuffer = new String[len]; // temporär textsträng som read-objektet returnerar textraden till.



    BufferedReader br; 

    try {
        InputStream input = assetManager.open(text_file);
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input, "UTF-8"));
        //bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getClass().getResourceAsStream(text_file)));
        String line;
        int i = 0;
        while ( (line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            stringBuffer[i] = line; // läs in rader från textfilen
            i++;
        }
        br.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException fnde) {
        //fnde.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("filerna kunde inte hittas");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    splitString(stringBuffer, index);   
}


private void splitString(String[] str, int index) {

    int nCols = this.stringObjects.get(index)[0].length; // antal kolumner
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {

        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(str[i]);

        for (int j = 0; j < nCols; j++) {

            this.stringObjects.get(index)[i][j] = st.nextToken();
        }
    }
}
```

since its 9 files that is to be loaded this read-method are called 9 times. Could this be the source to te memory leak?

Greatful for answer

EDIT: I choosed to show the whole class. Thanks again!!!

Comment: It is not the context that is consuming memory. You only pass a reference. BufferedReader uses 8kb by default so even if this leaks there is not much threre. What does splitString do? and what is the size of the actual Strings in the stringBuffer?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because of the String[] you are using to store read lines. Can you try it with a StringBuilder instead of String[] ?

```
// stringBuffer[i] = line;
stringBuilder.append(line);
```

Comment: I answer from my other account at stack. .. I made an update - you can see the whole class now. Thanks. Maybe I'll try stringbuilder but cannot see why its less memory consuming

Comment: It should not be less memory consuming. Stringbuilder is only useful when you change the string. You are not changing the string after you create it. If you use the code above you just get one large string instead of x number of smaller strings

Comment: I don't know the real problem and where memory leaks occurs. But assuming you have too many lines that you are reading from the text file, this way you will use lot's of memory. If each line creates a String Object that means another allocation in the memory. But using string builder will only allocate one memory space.